# Laravel or MySQL where correctly word

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question. I can not solve it.

I have this database

```
+--------+---------------+
|    id  |      name     |
+--------+---------------+
|    1   |     backup    |
+--------+---------------+
|    2   |     BACKUP    |
+--------+---------------+
```

My Model is Post
I use where clause to find name  called backup

```
Post::where('name','backup')->get();
```

But i got 2 posts not 1 post

Please help me this problem
Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15254) is a good answer to your question.

Comment: @nakov nope. It is not. I want to find id 1 not 2.

Comment: problem is where BINARY in laravel

Answer (score 0):

U have to create case-sensitive query

`Post::whereRaw("BINARY 'name'= ?", array('backup'))->first()`

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` returns a collection.
Use `first()` to retrieve the first matching record.

```
  Post::where('name','=','backup')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
Post::where('name', 'LIKE', 'backup')->first();
```